# How can I get firebase deploy --email or --token parameters to work?

Tags: firebase, travis-ci, firebase-hosting

I'm having trouble deploying travis CI with firebase using these firebase commands:

```
firebase deploy --email ${FIREBASE_USERNAME} --password ${FIREBASE_PASSWORD}
firebase deploy --token ${FIREBASE_TOKEN}
```

It does not like `--email` option and it does seem that it takes `--token` but does not work with my firebase auth token I can get from my firebase app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: found this https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools. maybe the token I had is not the right one. I am doing a test now agian.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The email option was removed in the 2.0 release of the CLI.

Use [`firebase login:ci`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#using-with-ci-systems) to generate a token.

> 1. On a machine with a browser, install the Firebase CLI.
> 2. Run firebase
>      login:ci to log in and print out a new access token (the current CLI
>      session will not be affected).
> 3. Store the output token in a secure but accessible way in your CI system.

Comment: But the access token expires after a month. Anyone know a way around that?

Comment: `firebase deploy --token "$FIREBASE_TOKEN" --non-interactive`

Comment: firebase now says that login:ci is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Another firebase deployment option in travis-ci is to use dpl (https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl) which is a deployment provider

OPTIONS

- token: Your Firebase CI Access Token (generated from firebase login:ci)
- project: Deloy to a different Firebase Project than specified in firebase.json
- public: Specifies which directory to upload to Firebase Hosting.
- ignore: Specifies the files to ignore on deploy. (similar to .gitignore)

EXAMPLE

```
dpl --provider=firebase --token=<token> --project=<project>
```

What is really cool about using this deployment provider utility is that you can deploy to one or more firebase hosted applications from a single project commit...

```
after_script:
  - dpl --provider=firebase --token=${FIREBASE_TOKEN} --project=${PROJECT_ONE}
  - dpl --provider=firebase --token=${FIREBASE_TOKEN} --project=${PROJECT_TWO}
```

References:

- (firebase.json) https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html
- (dpl --provider=firebase) https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl#firebase

*Note: One thing you will need to consider is how you set FIREBASE_URL as a constant in each hosted application if they need to use the same code base but a separate Firebase for storing data.*

Comment: I have 5  firebase projects that have the same code, can I update all 5 projects from single GitHub repo from Travis?? and that FIREBASE_TOKEN is unique or I need for every project to generate tokens?

Comment: that PROJECT_ONE you say what is ? the name of my firebase project the URL of that project ??

Comment: I'm getting ⚠  Your CLI authentication needs to be updated to take advantage of new features.
⚠  Please run firebase login --reauth